# Viewing XP CD in Vista

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CD Burned in XP isn't readable in Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/27599/cd-burned-in-xp-isnt-readable-in-vista)

I burned a CD while I had Windows XP.  I now have Vista and I cannot open the Cd that was
burned in XP.  It says it was not formatted.  Is there any way I can get this CD to view on
my Vista?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate...http://superuser.com/questions/114368/udf-reader-for-cds-on-vista-32

Comment: And here...http://superuser.com/questions/27599/cd-burned-in-xp-isnt-readable-in-vista

Answer (score 1):

Try this trial software, see if it can read the disc, most likely it is in UDF format which can only be read on the PC that created it or a PC with UDF reader software.

http://www.cdroller.com/

Another problem is that the disc was never finalized.

.